# image upload and cropping in mvc3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, image

Have never uploaded a file / image  :)

again, will try to explain as much as possible..

Have a MVC3 application. the user needs to have the option to Upload a Image , crop it as required and then it should be saved as byte[] in db ..

would appreciate any help for telling how to upload a image, crop it (jQuery), send it to server as byte[] and then retrieve later for viewing when user logs in ..

have looked at jCrop but am not aware of how to upload an image, and load it in the HTML file for jCrop to use.

As said, using MVC3 with Razor view engine.

EDIT:

Have used the following ViewPage code:

```
<form action="/home/index" method="post">

    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="upload" />

</form>
```

And the following controller Action

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {

            return View();
        }
```

but the parameter 'file' is null

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) What problems did you encounter with your code?

Comment: have no idea where to begin :)

Comment: The documentation of jCrop would be a good start: http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop_Manual.html

Comment: I would take a look at a combination of http://fineuploader.com/ and http://imageresizing.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the support ..

have solved the problem using System.Web.Helpers for managing image receipt at the controller and using its method to crop an image after receiving the co-ordinates from Jcrop .. Then again using a webhelper function to convert the Image to byte[]  ..

thank you for the kind suggestion though ..

Comment: and yes, please do remember to add the enctype attribute and setting it to multipart/form-data in the form tag for sending files to the server :) .. otherwise the file may not be sent at all.

Comment: @MDDDC . please accept my sincerest apologies as i am off this project from a long time an do not have access to its source code. however as i can remember, you first upload and save file at a temp location on server and retrive that file and path for the next view (for cropping). jcrop sends some attributes like, height, width, x,y start . you can use that send those parameters to another action method and crop the image. the library used was system.web.helpers containing all these functions.